# Prevent Facebook from loading comments from the canonical url?

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments, canonical-link

I have a Facebook comments plugin loading comments for URLs on example.com (e.g. example.com/sample-post), but it is loading comments for the rel=canonical link that is specified in the page head.

Is there any way to prevent this or force Facebook to load comments from example.com/sample-post?

Comment: _Why_ do you have your canonical URL pointing elsewhere to begin with? If `example.com/sample-post` is important enough to warrant that people leave specific comments pertaining to it, then IMHO it makes very little sense that canonical would be something else.

Comment: It is for a news aggregator that pulls in RSS feeds, so the canonical link goes to the original post on the source website (i.e. forbes.com/sample-post). Would like to use FB comments, but want the comments to pertain to the example.com/sample-post only. As it stands now it is pulling in comments for forbes.com/sample-post

Comment: Try and specify `og:url` via meta tag, and have that point to your URL. Facebook prioritizes that one over canonical, I think. Don’t forget to re-scrape to clear Facebook’s cache. Already made comments will stay tied to the URL used at the time though.

Comment: @CBroe YES! That was it-- thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CBroe suggested, updating the og:url fixed this issue, while still keeping canonical intact!

In case anyone here runs into this issue when using The SEO Framework, working code was:

```
add_filter( 'the_seo_framework_ogurl_output', function( $url, $id ) {

  if ( is_singular() ) {
      // Change singular URL here.
      $url = get_permalink();
  } else {
      // Change term/taxonomy URL here.
  }

  return $url;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Thank you!